# simple_html_dom parsing issues

Tags: php, codeigniter, parsing, simple-html-dom

I have the following controller in my new codeigniter application,which scraps data from a webpage.
But when I run the script I am getting the following error in PHP.`Trying to get property of non-object` at `echo $td->nodeValue;`

I couldn't find any error in my code.Why is this happening ?.
Any solution.
I am attaching the code [here](http://pastebin.com/sRqhkBFp)

Comment: Is `nodeValue` an attribute of your td nodes ?

Comment: You can only call methods & properties of the `simple_html_dom` object... You're probably looking for `$td->plaintext` or `$td->innertext`... Check [`the doc`](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/manual_api.htm) for more details...

Comment: That's not simple html dom, that's DomDocument. Simple doesn't use `nodeValue`.

Comment: @Enissay : I tried plain text and innertext ,but shows same problem.I think td is not an object ..Why is that so?

Answer (score 1):

Unless I am mistaken, which is possible, $td should be your actual value to echo, not $td->nodeValue. What happens when you var_dump($td)? or print_r($td)?

Comment: var_dumb returns a long text with some arrays

Comment: @JinuJosephDaniel Than maybe what you are looking for can be accessed by one of those array keys like: $td['nodeValue']

Answer (score 1):

What is this returning?:

```
$tds = $html->getElementsByTagName('td');
```

The error means that the $td variable does not have a "nodeValue" property, actually td may be the string value itself.

Check what `$tds` is first.